# How to get table data as rows and columns from wikipedia api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

When I tried to get table data as json, I could find distinguishable children in json output of the following query:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=List_of_football_clubs_in_India&prop=wikitext&section=3&format=json

I want to get the rows and columns of this table (the text) :-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_football_clubs_in_India#Assam

The JSON output seems complicated and I don't find a good way to extract text from it.

*(I am doing this in Javascript (Node.js)*

Please help..

Comment: I want the text fields of tables (rows and columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will slow down performance a bit (It seems, but I'm not sure if any other faster way exists). 
This can be done by setting `prop=text` and then parsing the obtained HTML using JSDOM (comes with/for Node.js)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, what you expect. Your API request to the page is actually returning the wikitext encapsulated into a JSON structure. However, the wikitext (where the table is part of) is not JSON, so you can not really interpret it as such.

I'm also not quite sure, what information you want to have. If you want to have the football clubs in the table, then your only bet is to parse the wikitext (you can also return the actual parsed HTML from the API to make it "easier") and go through the data yourself. However, this is probably an error prone and not fun task.

So, if you want to get all football clubs of india in a structured data format, I would probably better try Wikidata for that. It allows you to crunch structured data for the information you need (and also get you the links to Wikipedia articles, if the objects has a link to a Wikipedia page). In your use case, it's probably a good idea to try out the [Wikidata Query service](https://query.wikidata.org/).

There you could issue a query like:

```
SELECT ?itemLabel ?sitelink WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q476028;
        wdt:P17 wd:Q668.
  ?sitelink schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>;
            schema:about ?item.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

which queries a list of all football clubs in India and returns you a list with the item label as well as the link to the english Wikipedia article:
https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fsitelink%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ476028%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ668.%0A%20%20%3Fsitelink%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D

Answer (score 0):

Assume that this is the `res` is the data that you get from the wiki

```js
//This will get you the innermost part of the object which is the text you want
let wikiText = res.parse.wikitext['*'];

//This will strip out all the numbers and non-alphabet charater.
let pureText=wikitext.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\s]+/g, ' ');
```

The above code can give you clean access to the text; however, how you are going to separate the column and row is up to you.

Comment: This helped in removing unnecessary characters, but the main problem is that  `text['*']` is a single object and can't be iterated for each lines in it.

Comment: Ture. Maybe we can tokenize each word?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but there is an [API](https://www.wikitable2json.com/) for this. You can supply a page title and it will return the tables of your choice in JSON.